# Getting CORS error while using in-app navigation on an iframe in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, iframe, navigation, same-origin-policy

I am to web app development and I am now stuck on this problem. I need to use an iframe for some pages in my Ionic VUe app. I need to be able to navigate the iframe using back and forward buttons that are part of the app itself.

```
navigateBack() {
        const iframe = this.$refs.izus as HTMLIFrameElement;
        iframe.contentWindow?.history.back();
    },
```

This code however gives me a cors error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

The iframe website is running in an apache web server on localhost:80 and has `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` set in httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf and .htaccess files.
Does anybody know why I'm still getting the error?

Comment: My dear friend, CORS errors are related to backend services. if you have nginx or apache or simply any backend service, THEY should add headers to the responses they send to you.

Comment: This is not a CORS error.